# Getting 400 bad request error for params in url

Tags: reactjs, express, mongoose, fetch, bad-request

I am trying to fetch the data from the data base It works fine in the postman but throwing error when I run it on localhost
Backend route for getting all students
user needs to be signedIn , authenticated and Admin

```js
// listng route
router.get(
  "/students/:userId",
  isSignedIn,
  isAuthenticated,
  isAdmin,
  getAllStudents
);
```

controller for handling request in backend

```js
exports.getAllStudents = (req, res) => {
  let sortBy = req.query.sortBy ? req.query.sortBy : "_id";

  let limit = req.query.limit ? parseInt(req.query.limit) : 8;
  Student.find()
    .select("-address")
    .populate("faculty")
    .sort([[sortBy, "asc"]])
    .limit(limit)
    .exec((err, students) => {
      if (err) {
        return res.status(400)({
          error: "No students found",
        });
      }
      res.json(students);
    });
};
```

Above code will works fine with postman but when I connect it with frontend it gives an following error

```js
**Fetching API calls atb frontend**
export const getAllStudents = (userId, token) => {
  return fetch(`${API}/students/${userId}`, {
    method: "GET",
    headers: {
      Accept: "application/json",
      Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
    },
  })
    .then((response) => {
      console.log("res :", response);
      return response.json();
    })
    .catch((err) => console.log(err));
};
```

**Route for frontend**

```
        <AdminRoutes path="/admin/students" exact component={ManageStudents} />
```

**Error- It saying that ${userId} id undefined**

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your issue is in frontend. Are you sure that you are passing `userId` to  `getAllStudents` function? Because from your network result it seems that you forgot to pass any of parameters to that function. It would be easier to answer if you would share code where you initiate call to that function.

Comment: Thank you for help. I get my mistake . I am not passing the userId and the token to the function , for that reason error will be occurred . Now its working properly.